# Как сделать аналог Python консоли?

Tags: python, tkinter

Недавно начал писать текстовый редактор на языке python. При нажатии на кнопку "run" запускается нужный файл . Например:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
c=Tk()
def com():
   os.startfile("example.py")
run=Button(c,text="run", command=com)
run.pack()
c.mainloop()
```

Но возникла одна проблема. При запуске таких программ как :`print("Hello,world")` консоль открывается и сразу же закрывается. Вот и появилась идея сделать консоль которая не закрывалась бы при запуске программ без цикла while. Но как я не старался ничего у меня не получилось.

Comment: Добавьте в конец после print("Hello,world") - os.system("pause") И не будет консоль закрываться. Но нужно в каждый такой файл добавлять

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Можешь просто добавить `input()` в конце файла. В итоге чтобы консоль закрылась нужно нажать на любую клавишу.
P.S. Так-же в `input()` можно добавить текст, например: `input("Типа Текст")`

Comment: pause лучше, это функция есть в windows по умолчанию и, также надпись "Нажмите на любую клавишу чтобы продолжить" переводится на разные языки автоматически, в зависимости от языка системы

Comment: Ок, признаю ошибку)